# Jquery toggle input/span value not working

Tags: jquery, toggle

I created a simple test script to get the value of the span text and populate the value into input:
http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/8a923n0t/6/

```
$('.panel-body input').val($('.panel-body span').text());

$('button').click( function(){
    $('.panel-body span, .panel-body input').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.panel-body span').text($('.panel-body input').val());
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-floppy-disk');

    if ($(this).children('span').text() == "Check Out") {
        $(this).children('span').text("Save")
    }
    else {
       $(this).children('span').text("Check Out");
    }
});
```

This isn't the problem. This is working fine.

...but once I implemented it into my actual environment, I'm not getting the values back. There's so obvious differences between the two, but it seems be slightly off. I'm not getting any errors so I'm guessing my syntax is off somewhere.

Here's the "real-world" version. Click "Check Out" to see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/uL1c8owv/

```
$('.patient-data.stacked li input').val($(this).next('span').text());

$('.nav-tools li a').click( function(){
var valueToggle = $(this).closest('.panel-heading').next('.panel-body').children('.tab-content').children('.tab-pane.active').find('.patient-data li');
valueToggle.children('span, input').toggleClass('hidden');
valueToggle.children('span').text(valueToggle.children('input').val());

if ($(this).children('span').text() == "Check Out"){
    $(this).children('span').text("Save");
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-pencil-square-o fa-floppy-o');
}

else {
    $(this).children('span').text("Check Out");
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-pencil-square-o fa-floppy-o');
}
```

});

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you remember `document.ready`, as jsFiddle adds that automagically for you !

Comment: I'm guessing I'm pointing to the wrong tag or something, but I can't see the issue

Comment: Is this what you want -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uL1c8owv/1/**

Comment: yes!! thanks adeneo! -did I only need to add function and return?

Comment: No, I added a lot more, and rewrote parts of your script !

Answer (score 0):

[Adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo) was able to help answer my question. Part of the problem was I did not add a return for the first part of the code: $('.panel-body input').val(). Also, there were slight adjustments made to the click event to toggle the children within the following: .patient-data li.

Here's the updated code along with a fiddle showing the fix:

```
$('.patient-data.stacked li input').val(function() {
    return $(this).next('span').text();
});

$('.nav-tools li a').click( function(){
var valueToggle = $(this).closest('.panel-heading').next('.panel-body').children('.tab-content').children('.tab-pane.active').find('.patient-data li');
    valueToggle.children('span, input').toggleClass('hidden').text(function() {
        return $(this).siblings('input').val();
    });

    if ($(this).children('span').text() == "Check Out"){
        $(this).children('span').text("Save");
        $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-pencil-square-o fa-floppy-o');
    }

    else {
        $(this).children('span').text("Check Out");
        $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-pencil-square-o fa-floppy-o');
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uL1c8owv/1/